# Why declare a slot as a slot?

Tags: c++, qt

If basically anything can be used as a slot for a signal in Qt (provided that the signatures are compatible), why would I ever want to declare a member function as a slot?  Is declaring a member function as a slot really just a hold over from the pre-C++11 days?

Comment: Functions declared as slots can also be called directly from QML, though that's redundant because we can also use Q_INVOKABLE.

Comment: I think it must be declared as slot if it should be possible connect it in a Qt designer. Basically it must be a slot in any case where metadata about function are needed.

Answer (score 4):

It has indeed become a rare situation but there are still some uses to declaring methods as slots, if you want to use the `SIGNAL()`/`SLOT()` macros in a connection (aka string-based connection). For example:

- If you use e.g. a factory to create instances of several unrelated classes, you can create a string-based connection without doing introspection on the involved object(s).
  A good example of that is `QLineEdit` and `QTextEdit`; they do not inherit one another but both have a `textChanged` signal and you could make a window where instances of the former or the latter are added dynamically to it.
- If you want to make a signal to slot connection where the slot has more arguments (with default values) than the signal.
  This is explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html).
- For connecting C++ Objects to QML Objects (from the same page), as signals/slots of QML objects are simply text in a `.qml` file.

The cons of string-based connections (or I guess pros of functor-based connections) are listed in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Marking something as a slot is pretty much just a leftover from old Qt versions and pre-C++11 days.